# Handling multiple applications under the same domain

Tags: iis, zend-framework, url-rewriting, arr, pimcore

I am having a application build using pimcore (ZendFramework) which is hosted on a Linux EC2 (Apache) instance and one more application which is hosted on Windows IIS.

Now I want both of these applications to run in the following manner:

- http://example.com/app1 will redirect to pimcore
- http://example.com/app2 will redirect to application hosted on IIS

I can't use subdomains for this. I was trying to use URL Rewrite (ARR) of IIS. But ZendFramework is giving the following error:

```
Zend_Controller_Router_Exception No route, document, custom route or redirect is matching the request
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean "redirect to..."? Do you mean "serve content from..."?

Comment: Yes. I mean, , if user hits http://example.com/app1 then content should come from linux under this URL

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a third web server to act as a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). This could be an Apache or a Nginx instance for example.

The reverse proxy will serve your main domain on port 80 and decide what address to contact in order to provide the appropriate content.